# Records from Murska Sobata - Hungary, Yugoslavia & now Slovenia

Tags: world-war-2, hungary, holocaust, yugoslavia, slovenia

I was surprised to find Trautman's were listed as Jews and killed in Auschwitz on JewishGen.com.  How do I find records from a Synagogue that was shut down by the Nazi's.  The Synagogue I need the records from is the one that used to be in Murska Sobata Hungary/Yugoslavia & now Slovenia.  As near as I can tell, there were no survivors.  The Rabbi was also killed in Aushwitz and his name was Lozar Roth.

Germans listed those that hid Jews as Jews.   Records from the Synagogue would clarify if that branch of the family converted or if they were hiding Jews.